# 1-11 Hz to DC voltage signal

Tags: dc, communication, converter, frequency-measurement, datalogger

I'm doing an internship where we are connecting all kind of sensors on a CAN-network for an automated datagathering.
There is one sensor that sends a 50% duty cycle frequency signal between 1 and 11 Hz.
So 1 Hz stands for 1l/hour and 11 Hz stands for 1500l/h.

Does anyone know which kind of converter can be used? preferable to DC
The converter should come in a room of 70°C (160°F)
For the prototyping I used an Arduino Due with an own-made shield. counting the time between each interrupt. 
But we have like 300 sensors, so creating 300 shields would be a plan B option.

Comment: Are there details of the sensor online? Also, what circuit was the shield and what is the complexity of the shield you designed that made it incompatible with a build of 300?

Comment: If the purpose is to connect this sensor to a CAN bus, then what is the purpose of converting the value to a DC voltage ? Can you explain a bit more, and give some info about how everything fits together? (the sensor, CAN, the current arduino shield...)

Comment: @Andyaka It's the Aquametro Contoil VZF II sensor. Because they need certified equipment on a ship and specially in the purifier room of the ship, much heat and oil...

Comment: @peufeu Actually that's a good comment/question. If there is an converter going from the frequency signal to CANbus directly that would be perfect. The meaning of the system is to capture the data in the purifier room and send it 100m further to the engine control room where a datalogger timestamps the data and storages it. In this way we can track what the ships uses.

Comment: According to the documentation of that device, you can configure it for PWM output, current signal, or frequency output. PWM to a microcontroller would probably be the easiest method of reading the values.

Comment: @Polynomial PWM configuration doesn't work. But I think I got the 4-20mA do the trick. Wich is better because I can then use a long cable to get out of the hotzone and there I find many converters being able to work at 30°C.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the clarification.

If the sensor has a digital output with frequency proportional to flow rate, it will be a lot easier to use this directly with a microcontroller.

There is no need to convert to analog. In fact, PWM output will most likely be more accurate and noise-proof.

The typical topology would be:

- Several CAN-enabled microcontrollers
- Each acquires data from several sensors and transmits on CAN bus

So, you have a compromise to make with the price of the microcontroller modules versus the price of cables, ease of installation, etc. If you have, say, 10 sensors in close proximity, then it makes sense to wire them all to the same micro, and then wire that to CAN bus. And if you have another group of sensors some distance away, then compare the price of an extra micro with the extra cables and installation labor.

There are several cheap micros with CAN built-in. Check LPC11C14, for example.

Answer (score 0):

The data sheet for the flow measurement device says this: -

> Current 4…20 mA for flowrate volume flow, mass flow or temperature
>   signal to 4…20 mA

This looks a more sensible option in relation to your question: -

> Does anyone know which kind of converter can be used? preferable to DC

So, my answer would be to use the 4/20 mA output into a load resistor. This converts current to voltage and then use an ADC input into the CAN bus controller MCU.

Answer (score 0):

The frequency range is as low as you can use software solutions with a good resolution on an average 8-bit MCU. That is, without hardware timer limitation or interrupt timing problems, you can connect sensors as many as input ports. The main limitation will be the system mechanical and electrical layout and this way you will use MCUs as few as you can.

As the highest frequency is 11 Hz and I predefine the required resolution as 8 bit; making a timer triggering interrupt at a rate of 11*2^8=2816 Hz is sufficient. Inside the interrupt routine, sample every input and do the math and don't bloat things.

So, the simple answer is to gather as much as sensors into a mcu with digital sampling, then inject the data into CAN bus.